Confusion about integration in manifolds
I'm reading through Sean M. Carroll's text on General Relativity. In section 2.10, he explains that the volume element $d^nx$ transforms as a tensor density. Consequently, to get a "tensorial volume element", we can multiply by the determinant of the metric tensor, giving us $\sqrt{|g|}d^nx$.
He then explains that, when integrating a function $\phi$, we should integrate $\int\phi(x)\sqrt{|g|}d^nx$, rather than $\int\phi(x) d^nx$. However, I don't understand why this is the case. His argument for this is very brief. It seems a bit strange that we do this instead of just integrating the latter expression, as now we're no longer integrating the volume element, but rather a multiple of the volume element.
Is it because the $\sqrt{|g|}$ is analogous to the Jacobian in the multivariable calculus integral transformation law? What is a good way to think about this determinant being present?

I may have figured it out, actually. Say we start in an orthonormal basis in flat spacetime, as a simple example. Then integrating the latter expression does indeed give the right answer. But now say we double the length of the basis vectors. If we integrate the latter expression here, we aren't accounting for the fact that their lengths have doubled (and the volume units have octupled). Adding in the root of the determinant accounts for this, and this is what we mean by it transforming tensorially. Hopefully someone can clarify if this is correct.

That sounds right as far as I know. The object "$d^n x$" is defined using a choice of local coordinates and depends on this choice. We want integration to make sense coordinate-independently. Something is necessary to cancel out this dependence. On a general smooth manifold there's no way to do this but on a Riemannian manifold the metric lets us do it. (On a general smooth manifold we deal with this by not integrating functions, only differential forms.)

An example, in spherical polar coordinates we have $d^3x=dr,d\theta,d\varphi$ and $\sqrt{g}=r^2\sin\theta.$
